# Silverlight 4... Working with database?

Tags: database, silverlight, crud

I'm very new to Silverlight...
Is Silverlight development the same as ASP.NET?

I've started working on an Online University management in Silverlight 4 using Visual Studio 2010.  I know that Silverlight is client-side.

Please Explain how to work with a database in a Silverlight 4 application. How do you do adding, deleting, updating (CRUD application)?

Answer (score 1):

You have basically 4 options:

- Use an embedded database. Some examples: [Ninja database light](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-42-ninja-database-lite.aspx), [db4o](http://developer.db4o.com/Platforms/dotNET/Silverlight.aspx). Most are commercial
- Save your data using serialization onto the client's hard drive using [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) is the best bet for this, and so long as you don't have too much data this is quickest method.
- Use a web service reference in the Silverlight client storing no data on the client at all. All the CRUD operations are sent to the server.
- Use the WebClient class to access some kind of RESTful service, getting data back in a JSON format or similar. All the CRUD operations are sent to the server this way too. As with the web services, this will be getting the data from the network each time the Silverlight app loads.

Comment: If you're going to use a web service reference, I can recommend taking a look at RIA Services.

Comment: thanx chris... talk to you after review chris